# firebase ProGuard error (warning) with library version 11.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, release, android-proguard

I was working on 11.0.4 firebase libraries version. Today I've switched to the newest: 11.2.0 and when I try to build release version (with ProGuard on) I get the error:

```
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbdo: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp(java.lang.String)' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

And gradle console:

```
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes, check my answer below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was using API 25 (rev.3), the method `isInstantApp`was added in API 26. Changing `targetSdkVersion` to this version resloved the problem.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/31a16551910492321a6f7c291eb33e1458f39f0a#diff-a5f0b5ebe6a871aca1c5841bc0497538

Comment: Which version of firebase was this commit added?  Or in other words, what is the most recent version of firebase that can be used with SDK 25 as the target?

Comment: Probably 11.0.4 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Thanks - that's what I concluded as well.

Comment: Im targeting SDK 27 and still getting this error. =/

Answer (score 10):

For the ones who don't want to start using runtime permissions yet, you don't need to increase targetSdkVersion increasing compileSdkVersion is enough.

Comment: Sadly this is not a long term solution, Google are planing to crack down on apps that don't target recent versions of Android: http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/12/19/play-store-require-new-updated-apps-target-recent-api-levels-distribute-native-apps-64-bit-support/